# How to prove that $\hat\theta_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$ if and only if $a_n \rightarrow \infty $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: regression, econometrics, matrix, estimators

Suppose that $\hat\theta_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, is a sequene of estimators of $\theta  \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$a_n (\hat\theta_n - \theta) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$$ for some sequence of positive real numbers $a_n, n \in \mathbb{N} $, and $\sigma^2 > 0$. How would you prove that $\hat\theta_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$ if and only if $a_n \rightarrow \infty $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use,
$$\hat{\theta}_n - \theta = \dfrac{1}{a_n}a_n(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta) $$

Consider $\dfrac{1}{a_n}$ and $a_n(\hat{\theta}_n - \theta)$ separately since you know the asymptotic behavior of each quantity.